# Extract attributes conditionally and recursively for word document xml using xpath in ruby

Tags: ruby, xpath, attributes

[I have a word doc xml like :

```html
   <w:document>
     <w:body>
    <w:p w14:paraId="5B6351BB" w14:textId="0D9644FF" w:rsidR="00432348" w:rsidRDefault="00432348" w:rsidP="00432348">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="27" w:name="_Toc435537885"/>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>TESTPLAN</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="26"/>
      <w:r w:rsidR="00B46E57">
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> – PART I</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="27"/>
    </w:p>
       </w:body>
     <w:document>
```

I want to extract the text for `Heading1` , thus wrote the following  code, but it does not seem to work.
`@doc.xpath('//w:document//w:body//w:p[w:pPr//w:pStyle[@val]="Heading1"]//w:r//w:t')`
In place of `@val` , I have tried `@w:val` and also in place of `"Heading"` I have tried `'Heading'` for comparison. But still it returns a nil value.

Comment: By looking at the XML, what according to you is the value of `"Heading1"` that you expect your code to return?

Comment: TESTPLAN  i.e the value of <w:t>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typed wrong the `w:pStyle[@w:val]="Heading1"` part. It should be `w:pStyle/@w:val="Heading1"`. Then it will work.

Correct XPATH:

```
//w:document//w:body//w:p[w:pPr//w:pStyle/@w:val="Heading1"]//w:r//w:t
```